# Is there a time difference for people traveling at different speeds during a long period of time?

Tags: particle-physics, time, time-travel

I'm just throwing this out there for discussion/answering:

If person A sat in a chair all his life, in a house on earth (let's say 100 years),
and person B flew around in earth's atmosphere at let's say 1000km/h or 1000mph (which ever is easiest to comprehend) for 100 years.

Would there be a time difference for those people at the end of their life? would person B's clock have ran slower than person A, as person B was traveling at a speed closer to the speed of light, or is this speed too slow to be relevant?

Comment: There would be a time difference if B flew for only 30 seconds. Are you asking if there would be a *noticeable* difference? How do you define noticeable? Is a few nanoseconds noticeable?

Comment: You might want to check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Velocity_and_gravitational_time_dilation_combined-effect_tests.

Comment: yes any noticable difference is fine. is this computable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the most prominent example I know: The Russian astronaut Sergej Awdejew was in orbit for a total of 748 days (traveling at approximately 17000 miles per hour). Therefore he has time travelled a whopping 0,02 seconds into the future!

Comment: "Unfortunately, vodka isn't any better in the future." - Sergej, probably

Answer (score 0):

Let's say there are two twins. One on the ground and one moving through the atmosphere at 1,000,000 m/s which is a few thousand times greater than 1,000 km/h. The moving twin does this for 100 years, or about 3 billion seconds, then returns to the ground to compare clocks. The moving twin will have a clock that ticked more slowly by around 16,600 seconds. The reason I didn't use your suggested speed is that my calculator can't do decimals that small without rounding its answers.

$$
t = {\frac{t'}{\sqrt{1-\frac{V^2}{C^2}}}}
$$